# CMD copy command

Tags: command-line, batch-file

how can I copy all `.png` files in my current directory to a folder in my current directory called "src"?

I tried this code:

```
copy .*.png /src
```

and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

remove the forward slash so

```
copy *.png src
```

Comment: We have a winner!

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra period in the source, try this :

```
copy *.png /src
```

Comment: ..and that states src is off the root and not a local subfolder - remove the slash.

Answer (score 0):

If the src subdirectory exists...try

```
copy *.png .\src\*.png
```

Comment: Way overcomplicated

Comment: ... but nonetheless correct where other answers placed the target directory in the root directory, and also not prone, as other answers are, to silently doing something quite different to what the questioner desired whenever there's no directory named "src".